# Bash script hangs on specific input

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to write a simple script which does something if the first parameter of the input is equal to the -r string. But whenever I try to run this file, the program hangs and I have to terminate using ctrl-Z.

```
if [ "$1" == "-r" ]; then
 echo "check okay";
 for f in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name "*.h" -o -name "*.rb" \)); do
     if grep -q "$1" "$f"; then
         sed -i -E "s/${1}/${2}/g" $f;
         echo $f;
     fi
 done
 exit 1
fi
```

I have been stuck on this for the last 6 hours, it seems syntactically correct so I am unable to figure out what the issue is. Please help,

Thank you

Comment: If `$1` is `-r` then `grep` will treat it as an option, and hence you are effectively calling grep with a filename but with no pattern argument, I think

Comment: @steeldriver Oh..how can i pass -r to grep without it treating it as an option ?

Comment: At least with GNU grep, you can indicate the end of option arguments using `--` i.e. `grep -q -- "$1" "$f"`

Answer (score 1):

I could not test it with other `grep` versions than GNU grep but there also

```
grep -e -r
```

works as "masking" `-r`; that may work with other versions, too (in contrast to `--`).